# Three.js over background

Tags: three.js

I am using the three.js to render a snow effect. The snow works but seems to create its own div below the content of the page and not over the background of the body.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />

</head>
<body onload="init()">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ThreeCanvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Snow.js"></script>
   <script>

       var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
       var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
       var numberOfFlakes = 75;
       var allowMouseMove = false;
       var allowTouchMove = false;

       var container;

       var particle;

       var camera;
       var scene;
       var renderer;

       var mouseX = 0;
       var mouseY = 0;

       var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
       var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

       var particles = [];
       var particleImage;

       function init() {

           container = document.createElement('div');
           document.body.appendChild(container);

           camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 10000);
           camera.position.z = 1000;

           scene = new THREE.Scene();
           scene.add(camera);

           renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
           renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

           var materials = [];

           var material;

           particleImage = new Image();
           particleImage.src = 'img/ParticleSmoke.png';
           material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({ map: new   THREE.Texture(particleImage) });
           materials.push(material);


           for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFlakes; i++) {

               particle = new Particle3D(materials[Math.floor(materials.length * Math.random())]);
               particle.position.x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
               particle.position.y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
               particle.position.z = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
               particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 1;
               scene.add(particle);

               particles.push(particle);
           }

           container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

           if (allowMouseMove) {
               document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
           }

           if (allowTouchMove) {
               document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
               document.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);
           }

           setInterval(loop, 1000 / 60);

       }

       function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
           mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
           mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;

       }

       function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {

           if (event.touches.length == 1) {

               event.preventDefault();

               mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
               mouseY = event.touches[0].pageY - windowHalfY;
           }
       }

       function onDocumentTouchMove(event) {

           if (event.touches.length == 1) {

               event.preventDefault();

               mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
               mouseY = event.touches[0].pageY - windowHalfY;
           }
       }

       //

       function loop() {

           for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {

               var particle = particles[i];
               particle.updatePhysics();

               with (particle.position) {
                   if (y < -1000) y += 2000;
                   if (x > 1000) x -= 2000;
                   else if (x < -1000) x += 2000;
                   if (z > 1000) z -= 2000;
                   else if (z < -1000) z += 2000;
               }
           }

           camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * 0.05;
           camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * 0.05;
           camera.lookAt(scene.position);

           renderer.render(scene, camera);


       }

</script>
<h2>
    THIS IS A TEST
</h2>
<p>
Content here <br />

<p>&nbsp; <br />
<p>&nbsp; <br />


</body>
</html>
```

It seems like the snow shows up here. I have tried putting it in it's own div, adding that div to my CSS etc

It seems like the

```
container = document.createElement('div');
       document.body.appendChild(container);
```

is creating its own div but even if i change ('div') to something else in my css or use the GetElemmentByID doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should position the **div** using CSS to make sure it isn't in the normal flow (layout) of the document.

**For example:**

```
#snowflake-div {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

This will place the **three.js** snowflake animation over any content starting from the top left. Depending on the size of your div element and the desired affect this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to avoid adding aditional 'div' element to your html. To do that instead of:

```
container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

you should do this:

```
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```